# Aligning Elements in Xcode

Tags: ios, autolayout

I seem to be having trouble aligning elements. I want this UITextField to always be center horizontally, and stay towards the top of the app.

This is what it looks like on the storyboard:

[image]

As you can see, there are constraints set - which are blue lines (I think that means they are correct)

However when I view it in the simulator:

[image]

These are the settings in the Xcode pin popup:

[image]

## Question:

How do I get the UITextField to always stay center horizontally, regardless of device or orientation?

## Edit 1:

I took out all constraints, I made the UILabel the full width of the view, and centered the text inside. I assumed that this would make it center, but alas not.

Storyboard:
[image]

Simulator:
[image]

Edit 2:

[image]

See the two red squares, I'm not sure how to change that text. There are no options on edit.

I also cant see how to add the other constraints that you suggested.

Comment: **Remove the following constraints**: Bottom Space, Top Space and **add following constraint**: leading, trailing and height. Make sure if you are using **Any-Any size class** give leading = 20 and trailing = 20.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
remove your left and right constraints and set the following one.

Comment: Done that, still the same result.

Comment: Select the view and open the size inspector (5th tab) in the Utilities panel (the one on the right side). There you will see the constraints. Don't use that thing on the bottom to inspect constraints.
One of the possible problems is that your constraints are not active for all size classes. Also, instead of using `left` and `right` constraint, you can simply put a center horizontal in superview. If your screen is not wide enough, having left and right constraint set to 125 won't work for you.

Comment: @Sulthan I have done that. There were some constraints on the size inspector. I removed them all and added center horizontally and center vertically. So in theory it should now be dead center, correct? It still is not. On a side note, This view you can see is a XIB, which is loaded into a UIView on a ViewController - would that affect it?

Comment: @JamesG No, that won't affect it. The problem though is that your screenshot shows that you are adding your constraints for "This size class" and not "All". That means the constraint won't be even loaded on some devices